# How to exit dlv connected to a headless server without killing remote process

Tags: docker, go, delve

This question is about remote debugging of golang code using the delve debugger. Specifically, how to disconnect the client debugger without killing the remote process.

I run a process inside a docker container that needs to be debugged. The process is started in the docker's entrypoint via
`dlv debug /go/src/path/to/package --headless --listen=:2345 --log`

The docker container is started via
`docker run --rm -it -p 2345:2345 my_image:tag`

From my workstation I connect to the delve headless server via

```
$dlv connect :2345
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv)
```

At that point I do some debugging. When I'm done I'd like the ability to disconnect from the headless server without killing the process being debugged.

```
(dlv) exit
```

Unfortunately the above command disconnects the delve client from the headless server and also kills the remote process I was debugging, and since that was the docker container's entrypoint, the container stops. I'd like to avoid disconnecting from killing the remote process, how?

I've looked at the arguments to `(dlv) exit`, and cannot see one that would help.

```
(dlv) help exit
Exit the debugger.

        exit [-c]

When connected to a headless instance started with the --accept-multiclient, pass -c to resume the execution of the target process before disconnecting.
(dlv) exit -c
Command failed: not connected to an --accept-multiclient server
```

Answer (score 0):

Start delve with the following args:

```bash
dlv debug /go/src/path/to/package --headless --listen=:2345 --log --continue --accept-multiclient
```

This will continue the debugged process on start and allow you to use `exit -c` from a delve client. Ensure you clear any breakpoints otherwise your process will get stuck.

Source: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2324#issuecomment-1024700094